# on onmouseover taking time to display image

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

`OnMouseover` image I am getting from custom meta box and `OnMouseout` image is featured image.

Here is my code:

```
$image_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($postid), 'full');
$him = $post_meta['_hover_image'];
<img onmouseover="this.src=\'' .$him[0]. '\'"
     onmouseout="this.src=\''.$image_full[0].'\'" src="'.$image_full[0].'"  />
```

Everything is working fine but taking time to show image.

Comment: cache your images if you want them to load faster on rollover.
How to leverage browser caching: https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is likely caused by the delay in loading the resource. To help with this, you can cache the image at the URL by loading it in JavaScript with something like the following:

```js
function preloadImage(url)
{
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=url;
}

preloadImage($him[0]);
preloadImage($image_full[0]);
```

If the images are not dynamic, you can also preload them using CSS. More info about this can be found here: [CSS3 image preloading](https://perishablepress.com/preload-images-css3/)